# Android + Silverlight

Tags: android, silverlight, video-streaming

I am developing an android app for my homework. There is only one part left. I used the Silverlight to stream a video from my webcam, it works well on my website. Then i tried to display it with the webView as follows:

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://XXX.XXX.X.X/SmoothStreamingPlayer.html");
```

Then I tried to run it on the emulator. It said that the android needs to download the silverlight to run this. However, it seems that silverlight isn't supported in android.

I would like to ask, is there any library or any method for the android to run the silverlight video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a client software (like adobe flash) which is used to stream microsoft’s smooth streaming. Silverlight applications can be developed using eclipse but has dependency on .NET framework, Silverlight sdk and MS Build and there is no debugging available.

For video on Microsoft related technologies visit : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX